# JNeurosci Journal Review Paper Latex Template

Tags: templates, paper

Has anyone so far written a JNeurosci journal article. I am looking for a LaTex template for doing so. [image]

This is how it looks finished.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a template for JNeurosci on Authorea:

- https://www.authorea.com/templates/the_journal_of_neuroscience_

You have to log in to Authorea to access it I think, but having done that, you have the option of downloading a `.tex` file, via a button in the top right:

[image: authorea latex export]

Note: The output does not look like a published article, but neither should it. Most journals use one format for submission, and a different one for publishing. You are not supposed to worry about getting the format just like what you show in your image, only that you follow the [author instructions on the journal website](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/information-authors). That means for example using the structure described there, and that your document has double line spacing and numbered lines.